# magic npe in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

When I write

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
List<Candidate> candidates = (List<Candidate>) session.createQuery(
        "select Candidate from Candidate as candidate  left outer join"
        + " candidate.skills as skill    where skill.id =" + 1).list();
```

I have npe at second line

if I write

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
List<Candidate> candidates = (List<Candidate>) session.createSQLQuery(
        "select candidate.* from candidate inner join candidate_skill"
        + " on candidate.id = candidate_skill.candidate_id"
        + " inner join skill on candidate_skill.skill_id = skill.id"
        + " where skill.id = 1").list();
```

I have good result

why I have NPE in first example?

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/ui] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:41)

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run first query in query window?

Comment: then I get candidate+skill object. I want single candidate object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `select Candidate` from first query (do you have a field `Candidate` in `Candidate` entity)? 
HQL syntax for full entity select is `from <mapped entity>...`.

---

About your question:

**How magic NPE happens:** (...After a bit of debugging or HQL parser)
HQL parser - during AST building - look for a property-reference called `Candidate` and doesn't find it so try to resolve as a ClassName or a function (look in `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.LiteralProcessor.processConstant()` function);  Candidate IS a classname and parser threat it as a discriminator value (for entity subclassing) returning null.
After that parser, during translation of select's explicit list find `Candidate` with value `null` and try to resolve as a function because `null` is not a valid dataType (entity, primitive or other valid datatatype) so try to resolve them as a function; value `null` us used as parameter for function `SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction()` which as this body:

```
public SQLFunction findSQLFunction(String functionName) {
        return sfi.getSqlFunctionRegistry().findSQLFunction( functionName.toLowerCase() );
    }
```

and `functionName.toLowerCase()` cause the NPE.