# New Object with HQL - NPE on StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions, determineJdbcTypeCode

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I know this has been [asked a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027805/new-object-with-hql), but I seem to be having a different problem.  I saw that there is [a bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7473) in Hibernate that struggles with a SumFunction ignoring custom user types, but I'm not using a custom user type to my knowledge.  I'm basically trying to create a new object that is a roll-up of an existing mapping bean, however I receive a `NullPointerException` against some Hibernate dialect function.  I tried using both Double and BigDecimal as my `value` field type, but both provide me the same error message on deployment.  Please help!

Here's some code:

Mapped bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_summary_report")
public class SummaryReportView implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "region")
    private String region;

    @Column(name = "market")
    private String market;

    @Column(name = "proj_year_month")
    private String projectionYearMonth;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name="attrib_id", referencedColumnName="attrib_id")
    private Attribute attribute;

    @Column(name = "total_value")
    private BigDecimal value;

    /* other stuff */
}
```

Named query being called:

```
    @NamedQuery(name = "findSummaryReportTotalByRegion", query = " SELECT new com.rac.projections.bean.SummaryReportTotal(srv.projectionYearMonth, srv.attribute, sum(value)) from SummaryReportView srv where srv.region = :region group by srv.projectionYearMonth, srv.attribute"),
```

Total bean definition:

```
public class SummaryReportTotal {

    private String projectionYearMonth;
    private Attribute attribute;
    private BigDecimal value;

    public SummaryReportTotal() {
        super();
    }

    public SummaryReportTotal(String projectionYearMonth, Attribute attribute, BigDecimal value) {
        this.projectionYearMonth = projectionYearMonth;
        this.attribute = attribute;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /* other stuff */
}
```

Stacktrace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:145)
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.getReturnType(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:157)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:406)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode.getDataType(AggregateNode.java:83)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructorArgumentTypes(ConstructorNode.java:166)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:141)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1019)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2150)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2016)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1451)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:571)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1032)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:506)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 45 more
```

Comment: Maybe it's not a type problem but your value field is empty/null on some data sets? Could you verify this by checking directly in your database if there are maybe entries with no value assigned?

Comment: That was a good thought, @Ulf Gitschthaler, but the value field cannot be null as per database design.  Also, since I receive this error upon deployment--and not execution--I wouldn't think that I'd receive a data-related error until run time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will not be surprised if prefixing `value` with table alias as other fields will resolve the problem

```
... sum(srv.value) ...
```

Sometimes HQL parser resolve identifier as valid during parsing step, but fails with strange exception during execution. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149558/magic-npe-in-hibernate/18150380#18150380)

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner!  Thank you!

Comment: yw! I spent lot of hours for that damned NPE :)